# Cannot login to Drupal website

Tags: drupal-6

For some reason I have yet to discover, I cannot login to my Drupal website any more.
Attempts to do so result in loading my user page (as usual), but it is shown as if I still were a guest.
This is the case for any user I try to log in with.
No problems with passwords. No blank pages of death. Everything goes just fine except for the fact that the login is not affective: admin pages are still 403 forbidden and there is no admin bar.
Any thoughts?
I already tried clearing the cache and repairing the sessions table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it got solved. Some bright mind suggested restarting the MySQL server Drupal was running on. That did the trick, though I don't understand why.